# Want to check the working method of the Internal function of Input's pattern with onChange

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

i'm wondering the function that returns 'true' and 'false' in HTML 'input' tag.

I just added pattern and onChange in Input, however, it returns true or false.
Moreover, I needed to connect this, especially the return value parts to useState and connect to other validation check functions.

Could anyone let me know where can I find this function of HTML works?

- Again, I'm wondering the input's pattern function working way, and want to see that internal function in HTML, it just works only with a set pattern

Thanks!

```
const inputs = [
{
      id: 1,
      name: "name",
      type: "text",
      placeholder: "이름을 입력해 주세요.",
      errorMessage: "이름은 두글자 이상입니다.",
      label: "이름",
      pattern: `^[가-힣]{2,4}$`,
      required: true,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "id",
      type: "text",
      placeholder: "id",
      errorMessage: "ID는 최소 4자 이상, 영문과 숫자만 사용할 수 있습니다.",
      label: "아이디",
      required: true,
    },
    .
    .
    .]

const {
    label,
    errorMessage,
    onChange,
    inputRef,
    id,
    pattern,
    ...inputProps
  } = props;

  const handleFocus = (e) => {
    setFocused(true);
  };

  return (
    <div className='formInput'>
      <label>{label}</label>
      <input
        {...inputProps}
        onChange={onChange}
        onBlur={handleFocus}
        onFocus={() =>
          inputProps.name === "confirmPassword" && setFocused(true)
        }
        focused={focused.toString()}
      />
      <span>{errorMessage}</span>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add your onChange function for us to see whats happening in the code.

If you want you can specify onClick in input like so:

```
// the below function logs out event passsed to it
const onChange = (event) => console.log(event)

// later in the code:
<input onChange={(event) => onChange(event)} />
```

You can't pass function simply, because it will run every time component is mounted and not on specific event. To achieve invoking your function in reaction to an event, wrap it in arrow function as above.